# currency exchange database schema

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to create a database schema for currency exchange. I want to have information about various currencies every 30 seconds. This is the schema I had in mind.

```
Column                      SQL Type
FROMCURRENCY (PK)           varchar
TOCURRENCY (PK)             varchar
BUYRATE                     money
SELLRATE                    money
DATEANDTIME                 timestamp
```

All the information would in one table. Am I on the right track with my schema design? Any recommendations as to what I need changed?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track.  I would make the primary key an auto-incrementing integer and create a unique index on (FROMCURRENCY, TOCURRENCY, DATEANDTIME descending).  You may also want a unique index on (TOCURRENCY, FROMCURRENCY, DATEANDTIME descending).

Comment: Arya, I want to second the @GilbertLeBlanc suggestion that you create a separate auto-incrementing integer column for the PK. Using "business" values such as `FROMCURRENCY` and `TOCURRENCY` can lead to trouble - not 100% of the time, but if it does cause trouble it will be *big* trouble :)

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to index dateandtime if you want summary information for a time period.

Comment: alright guys, thanks for the suggestions. I will add the suggestions.

Comment: Is it Postgresql or MySQL?

Comment: You're on the right general track.  Your primary key is incomplete (probably); it means you can only store one exchange rate between two currencies (well, two, I suppose, since you could have one entry for USD to GBP and another for GBP to USD).  You should probably include the DateAndTime column in the primary key.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto It's Postgresql

Comment: What's the difference between the Euro to Dollar buy rate and the Dollar to Euro sell rate?

Answer (score 3):

Designing Currency-Exchange modules needs some more information due to country and financial market you are targeting.
For example in some countries that currency exchange is under central bank supervisions, Rate-Types will be more extended, like there will be a conversion-rate (beside sell-rate and buy-rate) for specific exchange-types. Business rolls will be needed to be studied before design.
Also in your design (In an exaggerated sample), having 200 active currencies, the user will have to do 200 * 200 data entry per day!
BTW
 I think you need to define some tables:
 
`Currency_Table`: currency table for currency definitions, details like name,swift-code, ... precision(that shows how many precision is acceptable and will be applied to the currency when **calculation** and **rounding** is applied.
In Currency-Exchange context (at least what i have worked on), there is a fundamental concept called **Base-Currency**,  it's normally the currency of the country your application is customized for (some applications use USD as embedded base currency).
Base-Currency is a currency defined in the table with a specific attribute. The Base-Currency will be the root element for all rate comparisons and calculations.
`Rate_Type_Table`: Contains Sell,Buy, Conversion , ... rate types (If having only sell and buy, you may ignore the table and just add two columns to rate table, like what you have done on your question)
`Daily_Rate-Table`: Daily data entries for exchange rates of currency

```
ID (PK)
Currency_Key(FK of Currency Table)
Rate_Type_Key(FK of Rate_Type Table)
Amount (decimal)
Date
```

Any record in the table, will show the currency value **in comparison to one block in base currency**.
 
For currency to currency rate, you will need calculation from source currency to base currency and then from base currency to target currency.
[Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) will be a critical mater in design and implementation of Exchange modules.

Answer (score 1):

Note this:

1. There is [ISO_4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) about currencies format. Note that currencies has different possible numbers after point. Preferrable storage format is integer, corresponding the count of currency minimal division.
2. Excange is the financial transaction. Check out for example [MTGox public api](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1) . I think it has the exact information about the transaction you would like to have in your table. The minimum is: transaction_id, amount of currency1, amount of currency2, exchange direction, customer_id, merchant_id, timestamp